# Simple question about choosing items from a box

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have a box of twelve balls and eight are blue and the rest red.

- When I choose seven balls at random, what is the probability of getting exactly two blue balls?

I know it's a fraction and the denominator is C(<strike>16</strike> 12,7), but I'm not sure about the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hypergeometric distribution. So you choose your blue balls, then you choose your red balls:

So $$\frac{ \binom{8}{2} * \binom{4}{5}}{ \binom{12}{7} } = 0$$

As getting exactly $2$ blue balls in a $7$-ball selection would require more red balls than we have, the probability is $0$.Note as well the denominator is $\binom{16}{7}$, not $\binom{12}{7}$.

Comment: Thanks! Been a while since I did probability and this is somewhat a trick question.